# Is a continuous function locally uniformly continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

Assume a function, $f : X \to Y$, mapping between two metric spaces, $X,Y$, is *pointwise* continuous, i.e. for every $\varepsilon >0$ and $x \in X$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\|x-x'\|_X < \delta
\implies
\|f(x) - f(x')\|_Y < \varepsilon
, \qquad
\forall x' \in X.
$$

Does this imply $f$ is *locally uniformly continuous*, i.e. for every $x \in X$ there exists a neighbourhood $U \subset X$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$
\|x_1-x_2\|_X < \delta
\implies
\|f(x_1) - f(x_2)\|_Y < \varepsilon
, \qquad
\forall x_1,x_2 \in U?
$$

A positive answer without proof, under the condition that $X$ and/or $Y$ are locally compact, is implied [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-122-04/S0002-9939-1994-1216816-5/S0002-9939-1994-1216816-5.pdf).

Comment: This will happen if $X$ is locally compact, by the Heine-Cantor theorem (a continuous function from a compact metric space into a metric space is uniformly continuous. The proof of this is the same as in $\mathbb{R}$, just with the usual substitutions). I think that if $X$ and $Y$ are fairly "big" and $f$ is a completely arbitrary continuous function, local compactness will be necessary.

Comment: For those looking for a reference to the result that continuity in locally compact spaces implies local uniform continuity: this can, e.g., be found in Searcóid's book *"Metric Spaces*" (2007) as Theorem 9.1.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X$ is locally compact, the result follows from [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem). If $X$ is not locally compact, the result is not necessarily true as Stefan's example shows.

Answer (score 18):

Let $I_n = \left(\frac1{n+1}, \frac1{n} \right)$ for natural $n$, and let $X = \{0\} \bigcup_n I_n$. Now define $f : X   \to\Bbb R$ by
$$
x   \mapsto
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{ if }x=0\\
\frac1n,  & \text{ if } x\in I_n
\end{cases}
$$
This function is continuous but not locally uniformly continuous at $0$.

Comment: @JohnHughes The codomain is $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem here is "only" that 0 does not have a neighbourhood in $X$?

Comment: @gTcV: $0$ has a neighborhood in $X$, such a neighborhood contains $0$ and all $I_n$ whose $n$ is larger than some $k$. The problem is in the "jumps" the function does at the points $\frac1n$. If you meant that $0$ does not have a neighborhood in $\Bbb R$ which is contained in $X$, then one could say yes, that's the problem.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a neighbourhood of $0$ is a subset of $X$ containing an open set containing $0$, but there is no open set which is both a subset of $X$ as well as containing $0$. I assume I am missing some technical point here, but couldn't find which one. Also, why is $f$ not uniformly continuous at 0, then?

Comment: @gTcV: We are dealing with neighborhoods **in** $X$, i.e. neighborhoods with respect to the topological space $X$. If on $X$ we take the topology induced by the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$, then a neighborhood $U$ in $X$ is (defined as) an intersection $U'\cap X$ where $U'$ is a neighborhood in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @gTcV: You can also take the restricted metric on $X$, this induces the same topology on $X$. An $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ is then
$$
\{y \in X \mid |y-x| < \varepsilon \}
$$

Comment: This example is unsatisfying. The given function is continuous at 0 but is not even "locally continuous" at 0, not to mention continuous everywhere as the OP asked, so of course it isn't locally uniformly continuous at 0.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret: What do you mean by *locally continuous* ? The map I gave is continuous (everywhere).

Comment: @StefanHamcke Ah you are right, the intervals $I_n$ are open. I thought they were closed.

Comment: Nice example.Very simple...................